# What is the meaning of lived in this context?

Tags: meaning

In this book, the authors present an interdisciplinary, scientific initiative that brings together the concerns for body and for culture to develop a single theory of cognition centered on the **living and lived body**.

Comment: What book, please?

Comment: Scientific & Mathematical Bodies
The Interface of Culture and Mind
Authors: Hwang, SungWon, Roth, Wolff-Michael

Comment: A brief waltz through the google looking for the authors has led me to believe that this book falls into the category of postmodernist lit-crit. Be aware that everything in this category uses an incomprehensible jargon, often using ordinary words in idiosyncratic ways. In short, nothing in these books has any meaning discernible from the language itself. *Living* and *lived* have ordinary meanings that cannot comport with their usage in *S&M Bodies*. You could ask the authors, but I'd bet you wouldn't be any less confused after they explained.